# How to display Angularjs variables with apostrophe within attributes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string

I have this variable in my Directive:

```
$scope.title = "This doesn't display correctly"
```

And my template:

```
<a title="{{title}}" href="http://google.com"> Link </a>
```

which renders this as a hover title :

`This doesn&#8217;t display correctly`

I also tried ng-attr-title, without success. Ng-bind-html usually resolves it, but I didn't find a correspondence for attributes.

I need a solution to properly display the string on hover

Comment: quite strange behaviour, could you make fiddle for it?

Comment: this works perfectly here http://plnkr.co/edit/CcWXzhjhOLCg1mEZIvkg?p=preview

Comment: I get the title via wp api with wordpress, it seems the weird behavour comes from this

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing '"' on your href.

```
<a title="{{title}}" href="http://google.com> Link </a>
```

Should be.

```
<a title="{{title}}" href="http://google.com"> Link </a>
```

After this change the apostrophe worked for me.

Comment: @Nkokoro Was this answer helpful?

Comment: apparently not :) he has not visited the site for 2.5 years

Answer (score 0):

Je may need to use &#39 as simple quote in your string
$scope.title = "This doesn&#39t display correctly"

Answer (score 0):

Title attribute works perfectly fine with an apostrophe, see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33p4z0cc/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <a title="{{title}}" href="http://google.com"> link </a>    
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("test", []);

app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = "This doesn't display correctly";
}]);
```